# acrobat javascript display a field based on a sum

Tags: javascript

I have a field that is the result of the sum of several fields. If the total value is 21 then a new page should be created. I've tried with the following code but I think that something is missing.

```
this.getField("Texte1).value = 
  this.getField("Texte9").value +
  this.getField("Texte10").value +
  this.getField("Texte11").value;

if (getField("Texte1").value == "21")
var expTplt = getTemplate("TEST"); 
expTplt.spawn(numPages,true,false);
```

Comment: Edit your post man. there's nothing to see

Comment: Hit enter twice after your normal text, then every line after that must be indented by 4 spaces to show your code. You only have to hit enter once after your last line of code to continue with normal text. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle link for it? https://jsfiddle.net 
because answering questions needs testing. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: There's a typo apparent in the first `getField` call: you don't close the string. Is that your problem?

Comment: I actually just saw, thank a lot